# Function prototype, without definition

Tags: c++, prototype, definition

I'am developing a library, that can't use Classes. I have a function I call when a get a KeyDown event and i want to call a function that i set the prototype for before in the library.
The thing is, I don't want to be mandatory for the user to define this function if he doesn't want to handle any input. But the linker won't let me define a prototype without a definition or set a default empty definition. What can i do?
I'am using C++ by the way...

This are the prototypes /

```
void keyDown(int virtual_keyCode);
void keyUp(int virtual_keyCode);
```

Comment: Use function pointers. Or weak functions.

Comment: **Why** can’t you use classes? That’s a … *bizarre* … requirement.

Comment: fwiw, the problem is not the declaration without a definition, but rather that you call the function in your code somewhere without providing a definition for it

Comment: got curious about weak functions and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35507446/what-are-weak-functions-and-what-are-their-uses-i-am-using-a-stm32f429-micro-co), seems to be a possible solution for your problem

Comment: I can't find how to declare a function definition as weak

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35507446/what-are-weak-functions-and-what-are-their-uses-i-am-using-a-stm32f429-micro-co

Comment: I've used a weak reference but it still gives me an error when i redefine it.

Comment: Defining a prototype function, which is called in the code, but it's not necessary for the user to define it. Sounds like a bug report in the making. You should rethink your design. And you say you are using C++, but cannot use classes... what's going on??? You're making your life unnecessarily difficult

Comment: @FranciscoGiancarelli Can you add your attempt at making a weak function to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redefining a function is not possible in C++. Read [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition) about the One Definition Rule.

> Only one definition of any variable, function, class type, enumeration type, concept (since C++20) or template is allowed in any one translation unit (some of these may have multiple declarations, but only one definition is allowed).

Overloading of class functions is possible with inheritance. Overloading is not the same as redefinition.

You can use function pointers, which you can reassign, e.g.

```
#include<functional>
#include<iostream>

std::function<void(int)> keyUp = [](int) {};

void unused() {
    keyUp(2);
}

void KeyUp(int i) {
    std::cout << i << i << '\n';
}

int main() {
    unused(); // no print
    keyUp = [](int i) { std::cout << i << '\n'; };
    unused(); // prints 2
    keyUp = KeyUp;
    unused(); // prints 22
}
```

It doesn't look the same, but effectively its the same...